# Velocity of three points

Tags: matlab, math, direction

I have 3 points (`a`, `b`, `c`) on the image at time (`t`) and 3 points (`a1`, `b1`, `c1`) at time (`t-1`). Each point have (`x`, `y`, `z`) coordinates . I want to calculate the velocity and direction of each between point. To calculate the velocity between point a and a1 is:

```
Va= sqrt ((xt-xt-1)^2 + (yt-yt-1)^2 +(zt-zt-1)^2) / framerate
```

similarly we will calculate velocity between `b` and `b1`, `c` and `c1`.
I want to ask that, to find the velocity of all point at time (`t`) I will add the velocities of `Va`, `Vb`, and `Vc`? and How can I find direction?

Comment: You need to specify which kind of variables `a`, `b` and `c` are. Are they vectors with 3 entries (most likely) or are the structs with one field for each coordinate - if this is the case, what are the names of the fields (`x`, `y` and `z` or maybe `xt`, `yt` and `zt`).

Comment: So are you saying that these 3 points all represent a single moving object and you want the velocity for that object? Or are they a point cloud and you're looking for the average velocity of the point cloud (like objects floating down a river for example?) As for direction, you must just use trig ratios like tan(theta)= y/x (or in your case `theta_xy_a = atan((y(t) - y(t-1))/(x(t) - x(t-1)))` and you'll also need another angle, probably on the XZ plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your velocity is a scalar, usually velocity is a vector.
To compute the velocity *vector* you need

```
v = [ (x(t)-x(t-1)), (y(t)-y(t-1)), (z(t)-z(t-1))]/framerate;
```

Now `v` is a vector pointing in the direction of the motion and its magnitude is the "speed" of the motion

```
mag = sqrt( v*v' );
```

`mag` should equal `Va` you computed.

Comment: Thanks, and Is it possible to add the direction and speed of all the points like   
`va= [ (x(t)-x(t-1)), (y(t)-y(t-1)), (z(t)-z(t-1))]/framerate;`  
`vb= [ (x(t)-x(t-1)), (y(t)-y(t-1)), (z(t)-z(t-1))]/framerate;`  
`vc= [ (x(t)-x(t-1)), (y(t)-y(t-1)), (z(t)-z(t-1))]/framerate;`  
`v= va + vb + vc`  
and mag(a) +mag(b)+mag(c)

Comment: Actually I have group of skeleton joints, for example joints of leg. So I want to find the combine speed and direction of that group of joints. So what would be best possible way to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

No, all velocities are vectors.  In 3D, that means there are components in the x- y-, and z-directions.

You'll need to use differences to calculate vector components for each point:

```
vx(1, t+dt) = (x(1, t+dt)-x(1, t))/dt
vy(1, t+dt) = (y(1, t+dt)-y(1, t))/dt
vz(1, t+dt) = (z(1, t+dt)-z(1, t))/dt
```

where `dt` is the time increment, `(x(j, t), y(j, t), z(j, t))` are the coordinates of point j at time t and `(vx(j, t), vy(j, t), vz(j, t))` are the velocity components of point j at time t.

Once you have that, the usual vector operations apply.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why representing the velocity as two scalars `vx` and `vy` is different than representing it as a three-vecotr `v` (as in my answer)?

Comment: Should be 3D, you are correct.  I need to add the z-coordinate, but the rest stands.

Comment: Actually I have group of skeleton joints, for example 4 joints of leg. Each joint have (x, y, z) coordinates. So I want to find the combine speed and direction of that group of joints. So what would be best possible way to calculate?

Comment: You have to do each point individually.  If they are connected, you have constraints as well: you'd assume that the link connecting them is rigid.

Comment: Suppose I four connect points as in this [figure] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nlbe56cbmc9b84/q1.png?dl=0)
Now If I take Euclidean distance between A-B, B-C, C-D and add them (A-B + B-C + C-D) or directly take Euclidean distance between (A-D) , it would be same?

Comment: You need to learn about vectors.  It's obvious that they aren't the same.